# What event do I have to wait for to safely access IWpfTextView.TextViewLines

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, editor, visual-studio-sdk

I'm starting out writing an adorner for the VS editor and my data is heavily based on line numbers, so I need access to the TextViewLines property on IWpfTextView to calculate my set of adorners.

However, when TextViewCreated is called, the property is still Null.

I tried instead waiting for the first call to OnViewLayoutChanged, and indeed the property wasn't null at that time, but the count of lines was '2', for a 50 line file and appeared to just be the first two lines.

What's the timing I need here to get a fully initialised TextViewLines that actually reflects the full file content?  Or am I misunderstanding what I'm supposed to get?

This is for the csharp content type on VS2010 SP1.